# Copying executable and DLLs to User specified location using CMake in windows

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

In CMake, I would like to run post build command which copies executable and required dll to User specified location automatically. Is it doable using CMake?

Comment: Do you mean [install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:install) ? (:

Comment: yes, but do you have good example that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what do you want to do. Here is 4 different solutions. There is probably others to add to this list...

**install() command**

If you want to copy executable and dll you just built you can use the [`install()` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:install) but it will work only when the user run `make install`.

**Setting variables**

If you want to do it directly at build time, you can use CMake variables to configure your build. These variables are described at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

```
EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH 
  set this variable to specify a common place where CMake should put all executable files (instead of CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
  SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin) 
LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH 
  set this variable to specify a common place where CMake should put all libraries (instead of CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
  SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

**A custom command**

If you want to copy other executable or dll you did not build yourself (binary libs, etc.), a good solution is to use a custom command. In that case it could be very tricky to have a portable solution working on all os to copy files. That's why CMake provide this feature (with others) directly from its `cmake` executable:

In command line you could use that:

```
cmake -E copy_if_different <SOURCE> <DESTINATION>
```

Don't forget you can call cmake executable from a CMakeLists file using `${CMAKE_COMMAND}` variable ;)

**configure_file() command**

And to finish, [the `configure_file()`command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:configure_file) allows you to produce a file from another by replacing variables by their value in the target file. If the source file does not contains variables, the target file is only a copy of the source. But I don't know if it works perfectly with binary file. You should carefully test that by yourself.

Comment: Thanks buddy. can you help me in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767436/create-a-directory-based-on-release-debug-build-type-in-cmake

Answer (score 1):

I added the custom command.

add_custom_command( TARGET FOLDER POST_BUILD COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different  SOURCE DESTINATION")

and it copies DLLs.

To copy executable, I used simple INSTALL command.

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Install_Commands#New_INSTALL_Command