# Create a directory based on Release/Debug build type in CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am working on post build, INSTALL command. After I build my project, I build INSTALL project,which copies directories to User Specified location. I have that working fine using

install(TARGETS EXECTUABLE RUNTIME DESTINATION CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/**USERSPECIFIEDLOCATION**).

I would like to change this to
install(TARGETS EXECTUABLE RUNTIME DESTINATION CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/**DEBUG or RELEASE**).

So, if I build using debug in VS2012, it should copy executable to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/**DEBUG** instead of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/**USERSPECIFIEDLOCATION**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is really difficult to understand your answer. Try to reformulate to be more precise. Please use markdown to encapsulate code in appropriate tags, and put real code. For example, cmake variables are declared with SET(MYVAR val1 val2...) but used ${MYVAR}. Please use the right syntax to help us understanding what you are asking.

Comment: My Question is.. How can you create a directory named "Debug" or "Release"?

Comment: the answer supplied below helped me. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll find an answer to your question if you look closer to [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3ainstall):

```
The CONFIGURATIONS argument specifies a list of build configurations
for which the install rule applies (Debug, Release, etc.).
```

Example:

```
add_executable(boo boo.cpp)

install(
    TARGETS
    boo
    CONFIGURATIONS
    Debug
    DESTINATION
    bin/Debug
)

install(
    TARGETS
    boo
    CONFIGURATIONS
    Release
    DESTINATION
    bin/Release
)
```

#### DEBUG_POSTFIX

But I think that all you need is [*CONFIG*_POSTFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aCONFIG_POSTFIX) target property:

```
add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
add_library(baz baz.cpp)

set_target_properties(bar baz PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX d)

install(TARGETS bar DESTINATION bin)
install(TARGETS baz DESTINATION lib)
```

Building `install` target with `Release` configuration produce: `bar.exe` and `baz.lib`.
Building `install` target with `Debug` configuration produce: `bard.exe` and `bazd.lib`.

#### Note

Note that for libraries you can use [CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX) (I don't know why, but `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` not applyed to executables):

```
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)

add_library(baz baz.cpp)
install(TARGETS baz DESTINATION lib)
```

#### Related

[target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries). See `debug` and `optimized`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question. I am searching for Qt dlls and install should find QtGui4.dll if release configuration is used and it should find QtGui4d.dll if debug configuration is used. How do i do that?

Comment: My program is finding dlls fine, but i am talking about copying dlls based on configuration not linking

Comment: Can you try to answer this question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792802/why-variables-are-not-accessed-inside-script-in-cmake