# Why variables are not accessed inside script in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a script called "**install_copy_dlls.cmake**", which is called to execute from top level cmake file as shown below.

INSTALL(SCRIPT "install_copy_dlls.cmake")

And, I have a variable named "**USE_OSG_STATIC**" which is set to ON if I use Statically compiled OpenSceneGraph and set of OFF if I use Dynamically compiled OpenSceneGraph.

I need to use this variable inside install_copy_dlls.cmake script.

so, here is how install_copy_dlls.cmake file should look like.

copy other required dlls...

if(NOT USE_OSG_STATIC) //if dynamic OSG

**copy  osg dlls**

here, I try to use "message" to print USE_OSG_STATIC variable and it doesn't print anything.

Can anyone explain me why I can not use variables in Script file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Can anyone explain me why I can not use variables in Script file?
```

`install(SCRIPT ...)` command works like [cmake -P](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt%3a-Pfile). So there is no variables forwarded
from parent script to child (until you explicitly define one):

```
> cat run.cmake 
if(A)
  message("A: ${A}")
else()
  message("A is empty")
endif()
> cmake -P run.cmake 
A is empty
> cmake -DA=15 -P run.cmake 
A: 15
```

Using `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(A 43)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P run.cmake)
> cmake -H. -B_builds
A is empty
```

Forward to child process:

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(A 43)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DA=${A} -P run.cmake)
> cmake -H. -B_builds 
A: 43
```

#### Solution #1 (forwarding)

Using `install(CODE ...)` command you can define variable for `run.cmake` script:

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt
install(
    CODE
    "execute_process(
        COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -DA=${A}
        -P
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/run.cmake
    )"
)
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DA=554
> cmake --build _builds --target install
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
A: 554
```

#### Solution #2 (configuring)

You can configure install script using [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file) command:

```
> cat run.cmake.in 
set(A @A@)

if(A)
  message("A: ${A}")
else()
  message("A is empty")
endif()
> cat CMakeLists.txt    
set(custom_script ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/custom_install_scripts/run.cmake)
configure_file(run.cmake.in ${custom_script} @ONLY)
install(SCRIPT ${custom_script})
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DA=42
> cmake --build _builds --target install
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
A: 42
```

Comment: I did also prefer *solution 2* over *solution 1* because it is much simpler if you want to pass multiple variables. Don't forget to use the *@ONLY* option. You won't be able to use CMake variables in your script otherwise.

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Very clear and easy to follow even for the most novice of readers.

Answer (score 15):

I found a simpler solution: set the variable in a preceding install() call:

```
install(CODE "set(A \"${A}\")")
install(SCRIPT cmake/custom_script.cmake)
```

This ends up rendered into the cmake_install script roughly as:

```
set(A "Avalue")
include(/path/to/cmake/custom_script.cmake)
```

which is exactly what you need.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks

Comment: In CMake `3.27.1` this doesn't work for me.