# How to create debug and release versions of libraries

Tags: cmake

I'm releasing a library which will be able to install headers and .a libraries for reuse.  I would like users to be able to link either to release or debug builds of the lib if they so desire.  I know that I can use DEBUG_POSTFIX like in [Create a directory based on Release/Debug build type in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767436/create-a-directory-based-on-release-debug-build-type-in-cmake).  My question is how do the users differentiate between the two?  They would still put `target_link_libraries(mylib)`, so I don't understand how a debug build would be chosen.

Comment: `mylib` could either be a target name or a library name to be searched for.  You don't specify that you are delivering a file that creates import targets.  So the user may just use a full path to the exact library they want to use and pick between Release / Debug as required.

Comment: We're exporting targets with MyLibTargets.cmake as normal.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyLibTargets.cmake` is correctly made they don't specify between the two.  `MyLibTargets.cmake` should properly set `IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CONFIG>` for the target `mylib`.  Then `Debug` maps to the `Debug` location and `Release` maps to the `Release` location.  This is done automatically using the `export` command for multi-configuration generator.  It's not really any different how a multi-configuration generator chooses `Debug` / `Release` libraries for any regular library target.